# TF-IDF calculation in Dask

Tags: dask

Apache Spark comes with a package to do TF-IDF calculations that I find it quite handy:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html

Is there any equivalent, or maybe a way to do this with Dask?  If so, can it also be done in horizontally scaled Dask (i.e., cluster with multiple GPUs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was also asked on the dask gitter, with the following reply by @stsievert :

> counting/hashing vectorizer are similar. They’re in Dask-ML and are the same as TFIDF without the normalization/function.

> I think this would be a good github issue/feature request.

Here is the link to the API for [`HashingVectorizer`](https://ml.dask.org/modules/generated/dask_ml.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html).

Comment: thanks... I went ahead and created the issue here: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/6663